# Solving $r'(x) = \frac{ p(x)-r(x)s'(x) }{ s(x) }$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can we solve

$$r'(x) = \frac{ p(x)-r(x)s'(x) }{ s(x) }$$

with unknown $p(x)$, if we are allowed to pick any $s(x)$ that makes the differential equation easiest?

Or, if we need to know $p(x)$, and can pick any $s(x)$ that we like (for instance, one that makes solving easiest), how do we solve this?

**In both cases, we are solving for $r'(x)$.**

Comment: This is confusing, do you mean to solve for $r$ not $r'$?

Comment: @ellya:  Actually, we can solve for either $r$ or $r'$ - I was assuming that neither is known.  So I'm looking to try to recover/get both at the same time.  I'm especially hoping that we can solve this equation without knowing $p$, either.

Comment: Why not just pick $s(x)=1$ and reduce the problem to $r'(x)=p(x)$?

Comment: Got something from one of the answers below?

Comment: @Did:  Yes I did.  I am thankful for all of the answerers' help.

Comment: Great. Surely you noticed that the accepted answer uses the logarithm of a function with possibly negative values.

Comment: @Did:  I didn't realize that.  I will make more of an effort to observe constraints and limitations from now on.  Thanks again for your concerns.

Comment: "Constraints"? "Limitations"? No idea what you are talking about (except the "limitation" of having a thought or two before accepting answers based on not quite correct arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given equation

$r'(x) = \dfrac{ p(x)-r(x)s'(x) }{ s(x) } \tag{1}$

may, as was done by user1337 in her/his answer, be solved by standard procedures available for first order, non-homogeneous, linear ordinary differential equations, *viz.*, as user11237 has shown us, variation of parameters; it may also be addressed, perhaps equivalenty, in a more or less standard manner by noting that the homogeneous equation

$r'(x) = -\dfrac{s'(x)}{s(x)} r(x) \tag{2}$

may be written

$r'(x) = -(\ln s(x))' r(x) \tag{3}$

for $s(x) \ne 0$, which as is well known has the general solution

$r(x) = r(x_0)e^{-\int_{x_0}^x (\ln s(u))'du}$
$= r(x_0)e^{-((\ln s(x) - \ln s(x_0))} = r(x_0)e^{\ln s(x_0)}e^{-\ln s(x)} = \dfrac{r(x_0)s(x_0)}{s(x)} \tag{4}$

which may be checked by direct differentiation:

$r'(x) = r(x_0)s(x_0)((s(x))^{-1})' = -r(x_0)s(x_0)(s(x))^{-2}s'(x)$
$= -\dfrac{s'(x)}{s(x)}\dfrac{r(x_0)s(x_0)}{s(x)} = -\dfrac{s'(x)}{s(x)}r(x) = -(\ln(s(x))'r(x). \tag{5}$

From (4) we see that the solution to (1), which may be written

$r'(x) = -\dfrac{s'(x) }{ s(x) }r(x) + \dfrac{p(x)}{s(x)} = -(\ln s(x))'r(x) + \dfrac{p(x)}{s(x)}, \tag{6}$

is in fact

$r(x) = e^{-\int_{x_0}^x (\ln s(u))'du}(r(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x e^{\int_{x_0}^u  \ln(s(v))'dv}(\dfrac{p(u)}{s(u)}) du), \tag{7}$

which may also be validated by direct differentiation; I leave this as an exercise for the readership.  It is instructive, however, to examine the integral $\int_{x_0}^x e^{\int_{x_0}^u  \ln(s(v))'dv}(\dfrac{p(u)}{s(u)}) du$ in more detail; we see that

$e^{\int_{x_0}^u  \ln(s(v))'dv} = e^{(\ln s(u) - \ln s(x_0))} = \dfrac{s(u)}{s(x_0)}, \tag{8}$

and inserting this into $\int_{x_0}^x e^{\int_{x_0}^u  \ln(s(v))'dv}(\dfrac{p(u)}{s(u)}) du$ we find

$\int_{x_0}^x e^{\int_{x_0}^u  \ln(s(v))'dv}(\dfrac{p(u)}{s(u)}) du = \int_{x_0}^x \dfrac{s(u)}{s(x_0)}\dfrac{p(u)}{s(u)} du = \dfrac{1}{s(x_0)}\int_{x_0}^x p(u), \tag{9} $

and using (9) in (7):

$r(x) = e^{-\int_{x_0}^x (\ln s(u))'du}(r(x_0) + \dfrac{1}{s(x_0)}\int_{x_0}^x p(u)), \tag{10}$

and since, by a calculation of what is effectively the reciprocal of (8),

$e^{-\int_{x_0}^x (\ln s(u))'du} = \dfrac{s(x_0)}{s(x)}, \tag{11}$

we see that (10) becomes

$r(x) =  \dfrac{s(x_0)}{s(x)}(r(x_0) + \dfrac{1}{s(x_0)}\int_{x_0}^x p(u)du) = \dfrac{s(x_0)r(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x p(u)du}{s(x)}, \tag{12}$

a solution which both agrees with, and is more specific than that posted by user1337, thought it is clear that, taking $x = x_0$, his constant $c = s(x_0)r(x_0)$.  Basically, what we have here is that $s(x_0)/s(x)$ is the *fundamental solution matrix* of the $1$-dimensional system (1).

The above presents the *standard* techniques for solving (1); but there is ***yet a third approach***, which is *specific* to the *peculiar* features of the given equation.  That is to note that (1) implies

$s(x)r'(x) = p(x) - r(x)s'(x) \tag{13}$

or

$s(x)r'(x) + s'(x)r(x) = p(x); \tag{14}$

we then observe that since

$(s(x)r(x))' = s(x)r'(x) + s'(x)r(x), \tag{15}$

we may write (14) as

$(s(x)r(x))' = p(x) \tag{16}$

which may be immediately integrated:

$s(x)r(x) - s(x_0)r(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^x (s(u)r(u))'du = \int_{x_0}^x p(u)du, \tag{17}$

or, once again

$r(x) = \dfrac{s(x_0)r(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x p(u)du}{s(x)}. \tag{18}$

Having obtained the form of the solution by several means, I close by addressing the OP's concerns about the choices of $p(x)$ and $s(x)$.  Evidently $s(x)$ may be taken to be any differentiable function without introducing too much extra work save computing it's derivative; so, I would say taking $s(x)$ $C^1$ but otherwise arbitrary is probably OK.  Since $\int p((u)du$ is needed for the solution, a little more care must be taken in picking $p(x)$.  If a closed-form, analytic solution is needed, then $p(x)$ must be chosen so that such may be had, whether by hand or by the hand of Wolfram Alpha.  But otherwise, I think, $p(x)$ need only be integrable for the solution to make sense.

In the light of [this small controversy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/how-to-deal-with-users-padding-their-answers-with-custom-signatures?noredirect=1#comment56614_14999) I close, as have so often done in the past, but perhaps not very often in the future, with the $58$ characters:

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Note that $s(x)$ could be negative for some values of $x$, in which case $\log s(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Did:  thanks for pointing this out.  Will edit in corrections shortly.

Answer (score 3):

In any case, this is an in-homogenous linear first-order ODE:

The associated homogeneous equation $$r'(x)=-\frac{s'(x)}{s(x)} r(x) $$ has the general solution $$r(x)=\frac{c}{s(x)}. $$
Using variation of parameters, we try the ansatz $r(x)=\frac{c(x)}{s(x)}$ in the original equation. This gives:
$$\frac{c'(x) s(x)-c(x)s'(x)}{s(x)^2}=\frac{p(x)-\frac{c(x)}{s(x)}s'(x)}{s(x)}, $$
which simplifies to 
$$c'(x)=p(x).$$
Thus the general solution to your problem is

$$r(x)=\frac{c+\int_{x_0}^x p(t) \mathrm{d}t}{s(x)}. $$

Answer (score 3):

Shortcut: the differential equation is equivalent to 
$$
r'(x)s(x)+r(x)s'(x)=p(x).
$$
Now the LHS is the derivative of $(rs)$ hence the solutions $r$ are such that
$$
r(x)s(x)=P(x),
$$ 
where $P$ is any primitive of $p$. That is, there exists $c$ and $x_0$ such that, for every $x$,
$$
r(x)=\frac1{s(x)}\left(c+\int_{x_0}^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt\right).
$$

Comment: this is nice but @Robert Lewis's answer has this at line (18) with $c=s(x_0)r(x_0)$.

Comment: He should put it more prominently, I doubt many readers will read that much.

Comment: @mvw:  In all good humor I would  like to say that I too often doubt that many readers read all that much of my often long-winded posts!  ;-) But I'll keep on a-typin' anyway!  If someone wants to know what I have to say, then they can just *read* the post as written!  If not, so be it!  Cheers!

Comment: It is your good right as author to write how you like. As a compromise for the sloppy readers, like me in this case, putting central bits in the top and then going into füll detail would help. Kind of an abstract. Go on!

Comment: @mvw I guess both your comments above are addressed to user Robert Lewis. To make this clear and to make sure this user sees them, you might want to start them with `@RobertLewis`.

Comment: @Did Sorry, you are right.